# Team City CI with Xcode workspace - Scheme "My Scheme" is not configured for running

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have a workspace with few projects that must be built as static libraries and I have schemes with tests for them. I want to configure TeamCity to build and test each of those libraries, but it does not work with following error:

```
...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace code/MyApplication/My Framework.xcworkspace -scheme One Of Tests TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES clean build -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
in directory: /Users/Me/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0f083d874fc6891
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator6.1
    TEST_AFTER_BUILD = YES
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace My Framework with scheme One Of Tests.
    Reason: Scheme "One Of Tests" is not configured for running.
Process exited with code 70
...
```

But at the same moment, when I clone my repository, cd into it and run command from above in terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace code/MyApplication/My Framework.xcworkspace -scheme One Of Tests TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES clean build -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
```

It succeeds: // **UPDATE:** It worked only for build schemes, not for tests

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

So it's definitely wrong settings in TeamCity. What can I try to make it works?

P.S. Schemes for building libraries work fine. Only with tests throw errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution. The problem was about poor support of SenTestKit with xcodebuild command. To make it works I had to go Edit Scheme menu and set Run step so the test scheme became runnable.

Thanks for solution [this article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/running-xcode-4-unit-tests-from-the-command-line/). There're few things was actually different, it is a Test After Build setting and macros. In my case it runs test only with YES option and I did not have to write any macros. Mb they fix the issue that was described in the article.