# xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace on CI

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

I got the error on CI:

```
Error: Command failed: cd ./ios && RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=true xcodebuild build build-for-testing 
-scheme "MyReactModule-Unit-MyReactModuleTests" 
-workspace MyReactModule.xcworkspace 
-sdk iphonesimulator 
-configuration Debug 
-derivedDataPath ./DerivedData/MyReactModule 
-quiet 
-UseModernBuildSystem=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```

Additional logs:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace MyReactModule with scheme MyReactModule-Unit-MyReactModuleTests.
Reason: The scheme 'MyReactModule-Unit-MyReactModuleTests (MyReactModule Workspace)' is not configured for Running.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110633/team-city-ci-with-xcode-workspace-scheme-my-scheme-is-not-configured-for-run might bee useful

Comment: @Gagan_iOS thanks, I'll look)